# WinSock: server receives bytes from telnet, not from client

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I am trying to write a client that connects to a server written by a labmate. I can make a connection to it by both telnet and my own client program using winsock. Telnet sends and receives commands just fine, but my client can only receive and not send any, despite not receiving any error upon starting `send()`.

A snippet of my client code:

```
// After connection.
// Receive a message first.
recv_size = recv(socket_test, server_resp, strlen(server_resp), NULL); // For check later.
server_resp[recv_size] = '\0';
printf(server_resp); // Prints initial send from server fine.
printf("\n"); 

int bytes;
char testmess[100]; // Contains test message to send.
cin >> testmess;
bytes = send(socket_test, testmess, strlen(testmess), 0);
printf("%d", bytes); // Displays the right number.
```

I'm wondering what the difference between send methods between telnet and the winsock `send()` could be? I have the socket configured as a standard `SOCK_STREAM` type.

Comment: `cin >> xx` will essentially only read up to the next whitespace. Use `std::getline` instead.

Comment: Assuming you are using TCP, you also need to handle only getting a partial message from `recv`, or more than one message, or a message and a partial next message, etc. It isn't message based, rather it's more like a stream.

Comment: You are also not sending a line break after sending `testmess`.  The server might need that to recognize the end of a command before sending a response.

Comment: You shouldn't be null-terminating or using `strlen()`. Just use the read count that was provided.